# assigning a clickHandler within the function and removing after

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
Popup.prototype.requestAlert = function(serviceRequest) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        alertMessage.innerHTML = serviceRequest.message;
        alert.classList.remove('hidden');
        alertOK.addEventListener('click', function(event){
            alertOK.removeEventListener('click'); // remove here???
            alert.classList.add('hidden');
            reject(serviceRequest);
        });
    });
};


Popup.prototype.requestConfirm = function(serviceRequest) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        confirmMessage.innerHTML = serviceRequest.message;
        confirm.classList.remove('hidden');

        confirmOK.addEventListener('click', function(event){
            confirmOK.removeEventListener('click');
            confirmCancel.removeEventListener('click');
            confirm.classList.add('hidden');
            resolve(serviceRequest);
        });
        confirmCancel.addEventListener('click', function(event){
            confirmOK.removeEventListener('click');
            confirmCancel.removeEventListener('click');
            confirm.classList.add('hidden');
            reject(serviceRequest);
        });
    });
};
```

how can I add event handlers on the fly and then remove it within the function scope so I still have access to `resolve` and `reject` of the returned `promise`?

**Edit**:

I've added confirm related code, the difference is that events for both OK and Cancel needs to be added and removed on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`removeEventListener` expects to be passed a reference to the handler that should be removed. Give your handler a name and pass it to `removeEventListener`:

```
alertOK.addEventListener('click', function handler(event){
   alertOK.removeEventListener('click', handler);
   // or better: this.removeEventListener('click', handler);
   alert.classList.add('hidden');
   reject(serviceRequest);
});
```

---

For your other example, create named function in the scope of the promise callback:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    confirmMessage.innerHTML = serviceRequest.message;
    confirm.classList.remove('hidden');

    function ok() {
        confirmOK.removeEventListener('click', ok);
        confirmCancel.removeEventListener('click', cancel);
        // ...
    }

    function cancel() {
        confirmOK.removeEventListener('click', ok);
        confirmCancel.removeEventListener('click', cancel);
        // ...
    }

    confirmOK.addEventListener('click',ok);
    confirmCancel.addEventListener('click',cancel);
});
```

Comment: wow I didn't know you could name the function while passing the literal, +1

Comment: Then you might enjoy reading [Named function expressions demystified](https://kangax.github.io/nfe/)

Comment: definitely, it looks like an in-depth article around functions

Comment: I just realized I can't do the same with confirm code, I've edited, any ideas around this?

Comment: because `confirmOk` has a different handler and `confirmCancel` has a different one, `confirmOK` function resolves, and `confirmCancel` rejects, an on either `OK` or `Cancel` I've to remove handlers from both. seems I've to define them outside as variable but wondering if a solution like given answer exists

Comment: thanks got it, the idea was to treat popups as asynchronous process that retrieves the data from the user just like a web service retrieves the data from a host and then chain the subsequent process.